# How to change the default style of CheckBox control in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I don't know how to change the Checkbox's Default color.I coded this line for Checkbox

```
<CheckBox  x:Name="chkRememberme" Foreground="Gray"  Grid.Row="4" Background="Transparent"   IsChecked="False" TabIndex="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Blue"   Margin="0,2,0,0"  />
```

In the below image, I have mentioned the style of Checkbox I require.

[image]

Comment: Edit the style of your checkbox.

Comment: @Romasz : I don't have idea so can you please provide a way and code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open designer window, right click on your *CheckBox*, then choose <kbd>Edit template</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit a copy</kbd> (or do the same in Blend). This should create default style in your resources (you can find the style also [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx)).

In the style you will find everything you want. The background color you are looking for is changed by VisualStateManager - edit suitable visual states and it should work. Sample - changed value of *NormalRectangle.Fill* property to `SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="CheckedNormal">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource CheckBoxCheckedStrokeThickness}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"/>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Sample image:

[image]

Note also that you may need to edit also other visual states than the one mentioned above - it depends on your need.

Comment: I understood your code , But I want to  chane the  color when user check the checkbox then how to do?

Comment: @HardikKothari Have you tried the code? In the style there are much more visual states. You can edit the style and do almost whatever you want.